# Tapestry5 - using HTML tags in Message Catalogs

Tags: tapestry

In the Message Catalog files, is it possible to using HTML tags? It seems to display the text literally on the page.

If it's not possible, is there a better way to include embedded links in the middle of paragraphs without c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the OutputRaw Component to achieve this:

```
<t:outputraw t:value="message:messagename" />
```

Or you could make your own binding prefix, something like `messagehtml:`

Example on how to add your own binding prefix:

http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToAddMessageFormatBindingPrefix